# Is there a hidden triplet here, as the notes seem to indicate 9/8 but the time signature is 4/4?

Tags: ukulele, strumming

I found this strumming in a book which confused me a lot:

[image: 4/4 strumming that seems it should take 9/8]

It seems it has 9/8 but states clearly that it should have 4/4. I tried to figure it out and stumbled over triplets. So my guess is it has a hidden triplet?

I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction to figure out how to play this strumming.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a 4/4 measure. Below I marked the quarter-note groups.

Perhaps you're confused by the dots *below* two of the notes. They indicate *staccato* articulation, rather than dotted note (1.5 duration) where dot would be placed right from the note, as the dot next to one of the eight-note rests below.

[image]

Comment: Do you know whether it's common to indicate *staccato* like this (in rhythmic notation)? I understand OP's confusion and would have expected the *staccato* dots further to the left, below the lower left part of the note heads.

Comment: @Arsak To me it's clearly staccato. The dot is below the note head. It looks fine to me. I think people sometimes confuse dotted notes and staccato because if they are unfamiliar with staccato marks.